# button to find record in another table based on field

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

On my form, i have a button beside a field (AppID) thats linked to records in another table (Applications).

Is there a way i can set that button to open the Applications form and bring up the record stated in the AppID field? it would make my life ALOT easier

im using Access 2010

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Where argument of the Openform action.

```
 DoCmd.OpenForm "Applications", , , "AppID=" & Me.AppID
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa141520(v=office.10).aspx